Opinion and understanding of a PR curve
I'm currently working on a model for edge detection. For the evaluation, I use this repo :
https://github.com/Walstruzz/edge_eval_python
I obtain this PR curve :

I don't understand why the curve is increasing and then decreasing, because I thought that a PR curve only decreases. So, I have several questions :

Does this curve seem coherent to you?
How do you translate the fact that it grows and shrinks? How to interpret it ?

Thank you very much in advance for your reply.
